# Reusing data contracts as view models

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf

Assume your solution has the following projects:

- Core (entities)
- Contracts (DTOs, service interfaces)
- Services (service implementations)
- Service Host (WCF)
- Client (ASP.NET MVC)

The client works with the contracts and not the entities.  Each view in the MVC project has its own distinct view model.  The MVC project has no awareness of the entities.

I'm considering the possibility of reusing the data contracts as view models so instead of retrieving a Widget DTO from the service and mapping the Widget DTO to a Widget VM, I will instead retrieve a Widget DTO and pass it directly to the view.

Is this good or bad and why?

Comment: If you never plan to use your DTOs in a different client (e.g. a WPF client, or another MVC app) then it's OK to use the DTOs as VMs if the DTOs handcrafted for the MVC app porpuses. In any other case I would do the DTO -> VM mapping. By the way I hope that you have a good reason for this complicated architecture: MVC talks to DB through WCF...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this good or bad and why?

If those DTOs strictly match the requirements of your views (which would highly surprise me) then, yes, it is perfectly fine to use them instead of writing view models.

But if you catch yourself using ViewBag because some property that is required by your view is not present in your DTO, stop immediately! Go and define a view model for this particular view.